# Change size of markers in scatter3

Tags: matlab, markers, scatter

I want to draw a set of points each with different colors.

Unfortunately the dots become really small. How can I change that?

This is how my code looks right now, but it is not working

```
% Draw with different colors
colors = ['b'; 'k'; 'r'; 'g'; 'm'; 'y'; 'c']
hold on;
for i = 1:7
    x = cell2mat(cluster_l(i))
    scatter3(x(:,1),x(:,2),x(:,3), strcat(colors(i), '.'), 'MarkerSize', 12);
end
```

But apparantly there is no MarkerSize property on the Scatter class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the size of the marker as [fourth argument (`S`)](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html#input_argument_d0e901187):

```
scatter3(x(:,1), x(:,2), x(:,3), 12, strcat(colors(i), '.'));
```

> draws each circle with the size specified by S. To plot each circle
>   with equal size, specify S as a scalar. To plot each circle with a
>   specific size, specify S as a vector.